# What function is the equivalent of torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss in TF2.0 for multiclass logits

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0, torch

I am sorry I am asking this question, it seems so stupid, but I have no other way to look for it. If you have some parallel documentation that easily compares this kind of questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Good people of SO, the SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is equivalent to it in TF2.0 : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

It's SparseCategoricalCrossentropy and not CategoricalCrossentropy, because torch's cross entropy does not use one hot encoding as CategoricalCrossentropy in Tensorflow does.